# ADO.NET how to identify a user's roles in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado

There is a database on an Sql Server 2012. The server has users who belong to different roles. The application is written in C#.  It connects to the database via SqlConnection. In Sql Connection I build the connection string with the user's stated username and password.

I need to know how to identify what roles the user belongs to in the database, so that I can configure my application appropriately.  How do I find out what roles the user has so I can log in through a single login window, but redirect the user to different windows depending on their DB roles.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please add example of roles and what implication a specific role has (different access to data, different functionality in the application). How do you authenticate with the database, do each user authenticate using their own (SQL Server) account? Are the roles defined in the SQL Server security or within a database table?

Comment: I want to log users through a single window, and depending on the role redirect to other windows

Comment: @PHeiberg - I have edited the question to make the OP's intentions more clear.  Being a non-native speaker of English, it was not hard to figure out what he was looking for, give him the relevant answer (which he accepted), and edit the question so it will be more clear to other users looking for the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he is asking how to know what roles the user has in the database so he can configure his application appropriately. It is OK to ask the user to provide their username and password, and build that into the connection string to access the database. This properly limits the user access only as far as the db is configured to give them access, which is what users and roles were created for in SQL Server - to authenticate and authorize the user connecting to the database through whatever application.

But if you want to know their roles in the database, so you can configure your application appropriately, you will need to read from the security catalog views in SQL server. These are views like any other views you create, only they are already created for you. You can read from them with a select statement just like you would read from your own tables and views. You might specifically look into the sys.database_role_members, which connects users to their roles. If you connect to the db using the actual user's username and password, you will still be able to read from these security catalogs, you will just only be able to read that specific user's information, which is what you want anyway.

You would use a select statement like this:

```
SELECT roles.NAME, members.NAME
  FROM sys.database_role_members role_members
       JOIN sys.database_principals roles
         ON role_members.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
       JOIN sys.database_principals members
         ON role_members.member_principal_id = members.principal_id
```

You can read more about these security catalogs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178542.aspx.

Comment: @MrsEd - this is not off-topic.  His English is apparently not up to par with explaining what he needed with total clarity, but with a little insight it was not that hard to figure it out and answer correctly.  This goes to the SO community's stated desire to be more welcoming of new users, especially those for whom English is not their first language.

Answer (score -1):

Authorization should not be done on connection string level, but in business logic of application.

When user gets logged in, you check for his role, and based on that you decide what he can/can't do.

Comment: This is a confusingly incorrect answer.  To check the user's role, the application has to connect to the database.  For doing so, in a database application, it is fine to use that user's stated username and password to attempt a connection to the database, which means putting them into the connection string.  If the connection succeeds, then the application can read the user's roles.  If the connection fails, the application can refuse the username and password provided.  This process would involve all three layers - i/o, business, and data.

Comment: @AgapwIesu You are obviously mixing user roles on the server and user rights in application itself.

Comment: He is apparently building an application that uses db user roles as the application roles.  Some applications correctly do this.